# Can Google Sheet data be inserted into a Google Doc script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs-api

I am a VERY novice code writer, and a teacher,  so I want to write a Google Doc script to find incorrect words in a paragraph in a Google Doc, and replace them with correct words. However, I want the correct and incorrect words taken from a Google Sheet worksheet.

I have some code (see below) which finds and replaces words (Hi -> Hello), but this is not user friendly.

[image: Find and Replace code]

I am experimenting with spreadsheets.value.get but it is beyond me at the moment. Am I on track or no where near? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think that providing your script as a string instead of an image will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Yes you can access an Spreadsheet with SpreadsheetApp.openById() from a Google Doc Script.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I would rethink even pulling in the values from a spreadsheet. You want to use a **javascript  object.** An object is a place to store key-value pairs. They are super efficient at both storing and retrieving data.

If possible, I would store the words and replacements as key-value pairs in an object, like this:

```
var myObject = {
  "hi": "hello",
  ...
}
```

If you try to iterate through each row of a spreadsheet to find the matching correction, your code is going to take a **long** time as your document and spreadsheet get longer.

You could store the words and replacements in a sheet, retrieve the range of cells you want, and put the keys and values into an object, like this:

(Column A is key ["hi"], Column B is value ["Hello"])

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET ID HERE');
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SHEET NAME HERE')
var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B100');
var values = range.getValues();

var myObject = {};

for (row in values) {
  myObject[values[row][0]] = values[row][1];
}
```

`myObject` would look something like this:

```
{
  "hi": "hello",
  ...
}
```

Now, just loop through your object and replace like you did in the screenshot you attached, like this:

```
for (key in myObject) {
  body.replaceText(key, myObject[key]);
}
```

Also, instead of simply searching for the key and replacing, you might want to use a **regex** pattern. The current way of doing it will not avoid changing "t**hi**s" into "t**hello**s". The pattern below will only identify words that match the `key` and not letter combinations anywhere in the text.

```
for (key in myObject) {
  body.replaceText('/\b' + key +'\b/gi', myObject[key]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. This site is "a bit" different than other similar places. Thinks like "First, congrats on your journey to coding and for being a teacher!" and  "I'd be happy to help if you need any further clarification." could be posted as comments once you gain the comment anywhere privilege but they should be avoided  on questions and answers as they are considered "noise". For details please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Appreciate the help Cameron. I've noticed that your code doesn't specify the name/ID of the Google sheet which contains the values. Does it assume that the sheet has the same name? Is the active Sheet? Cooper suggested a 'SpreadsheetApp.openById()' option which might be clearer but I'm not sure how it would work.

Comment: I'm also unsure what a Regex pattern is in terms of coding, but I was going to look into this by using wildcard * and similar symbols to help avoid the issue you described. Are they the same thing?

Comment: Gareth, as far as the spreadsheet goes, you want to obtain the ID for the spreadsheet you are using and do as Cooper suggests and use `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`. You can find the spreadsheet ID in the URL.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've added the Spreadsheet Id, but its bugging at the body.replaceText(key, myObject[key]); line now. Do I have to give column and row values as the Key entries? What does the Key refer to exactly?